# UnmanagedMemoryStream does not work with ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, kruntime

UnmanagedMemoryStream does not work with ASP.NET Core 5.0.
I have used to use UnmanagedMemoryStream but it does not work with "1.0.0-beta2 CoreCLR amd64" runtime.
I have used temporary the code:

```
unsafe
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count && pos < size; i++)
            {
                buffer[i + offset] = ((byte*)this.buffer.ToPointer())[pos++];
                ++cnt;
            }
            return cnt;
        }
```

It copies data into manage buffer, but it is slower that use it directly. Is there going to be a fix for this or this is conceptual issue?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? You can't find the type? Or it throws an exception?

Comment: That type is in the http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream/4.0.0-beta-22416 package, so make sure your `project.json` file reference that NuGet package.

Comment: Package is referenced. It does not work - means that after copy process the buffer has zeros in memory cells. I have made a fix - I've used native Copy - extern "C" void Copy(void* dest, void* src, size_t size); visa versa UnmanageMemoryStream. It's a pity but it does not work with .Net Core for some reason.

Comment: Are you saying everything *runs* with no errors, but the function doesn't do what you expected?